# Google Chrome Extension POST VS GET

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

This is my code

```
chrome.windows.create({'url': "http://example.com/upload/upload.php?pictureID="+ theResponse + "&userID=" + localStorage["id"]+"&username="+  localStorage["mainLogin"]}, function(tab) {
  // open window
});
```

this constructs a URL that looks like:

```
http://example.com/upload/upload.php?pictureID=123&userID=1&username=jack
```

I would call this method `GET` -- like how forms `GET` or `POST`

How can I open a window with `POST` data rather than `GET` data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to write a HTML page that creates a form containing your POST data and target URL and submit the form. 
Here's a simple example:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
    location.search.substr(1).split('&').forEach(function(item)
    {
        var input = document.createElement('input');
        input.type = 'hidden';
        input.name = item.substr(0, item.indexOf('='));
        input.value = item.substr(item.indexOf('=') + 1);
        document.getElementById('postform').appendChild(input);
    });
    document.getElementById('postform').submit();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://example.com/upload/upload.php" method="post" id="postform">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Say that's test.html in your extension's root directory. Call

```
chrome.windows.create({'url': "test.html?pictureID="+ theResponse + "&userID=" + localStorage["id"]+"&username="+  localStorage["mainLogin"]}, function(tab) {
  // open window
});
```

will open the website with POST method.